# How to setup C++ standard for vscode in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, launch

I'm running VS Code on freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Whatever I try, my language standard is stuck at input loop when i get start debug. I use gdb compiler. To check the issue I run the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
// main
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
     int n;
     cin>>n;
     cout<<n+1<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Already installed extension:

1. C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft
2. CMake tools

When I press Debug, my input is: 3 1 2 3
I want my output is: 2 3 4
but when i enter the input, vscode gives me 4 numbers while the input is only 3 test cases, and the result is only 5 ''= 4+1'' which is the result of the last number I entered

[my vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnHUQ.png)

This is my lauch.json file:

```
{
     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
          {
               "name": "(gdb) Launch",
               "type": "cppdbg",
               "request": "launch",
               "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
               "args": [],
               "stopAtEntry": false,
               "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
               "environment": [],
               "externalConsole": false,
               "MIMode": "gdb",
               "setupCommands": [
                   {
                       "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                       "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                       "ignoreFailures": true
                   },
                   {
                       "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                       "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                       "ignoreFailures": true
                   }
               ]
          }

     ]
}
```

and my task.json like this

```
{
     "tasks": [
          {
               "type": "cppbuild",
               "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
               "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
               "args": [
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
               ],
               "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
               },
               "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
               ],
               "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
               },
               "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
          }
     ],
     "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

When i delete all the things in launch.json file and Debug again,everything is as I want, from input to output is smooth as if nothing happened. Somebody explain for me please. How ??

Comment: You need to make the changes for the language standard in your `tasks.json` and your `c_cpp_properties.json` Edit: I don't believe your problem is related to language standard.

Comment: Please elaborate on *"my language standard is stuck at input loop"*. What does the standard have to do with the input?